# Can I use redis-cli with a connection URL?

Tags: heroku, redis, connection-string, redis-cli

I am used to `psql` which I can use by feeding it the connection string without having to break it in different arguments, that is,

```
psql postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>
```

This is useful when I have such string from Heroku, for example.
Can I do something similar with `redis-cli`? I want to feed it directly a connection string, such as the one that is stored on Heroku as environment variable when I install a Redis add-on. Is that possible? Example of the syntax I would like to use:

```
redis-cli redis://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>
```

Comment: I opened a feature request on the redis issue tracker: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3399

Comment: Thanks to Itamar for his reply both here and there.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

No, at the moment (v3.2.1) redis-cli does not support the URI connection schema. If you want, you can make a feature or pull request for that in the [Redis repository](https://github.com/antirez/redis).

**UPDATE:**
The `-u` option was released with Redis 4.0, see [Release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/00-RELEASENOTES). For example:

```
redis-cli -u redis://user:pass@host:6379/0
```

Comment: And thank you for creating the pull request: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/3409

Comment: My pleasure - I'll ping antirez about it so maybe it will be included in v4 :)

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino thanks for updating the reply - looks like I kept my promise (now I'm trying to do the same w/ redis-benchmark :P))

Comment: it should be `redis-cli -u redis://user:pass@host:6379/0` (note the ..-cli part).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @SergeyGrechin - fixed.

Answer (score 12):

For those who cannot wait for the next Redis release won't be able to update their redis-cli, I made a simple bash function that seems to work for my case (Heroku). This is to be added to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
function redis-url() {
  # Get the first argument as the URL variable
  url=$1
  # Parse and generate the command: redis-cli -h [hostname] -p [port] -a [password]
  cmd=`echo $url | sed 's_redis://\(.*\):\(.*\)@\(.*\):\(.*\)_redis-cli -h \3 -p \4 -a \2_'`
  # Run the command
  $cmd
}
```

I can then type the following in my terminal:

```
redis-url redis://rediscloud:mysupersecurepassword@hostname.com:1234
```

Comment: FYI, the `-u` option from Itamar's PR has already been released with Redis 4 and it's in redis-cli now.

Comment: Really? Which version is it exactly? It's still [on the unstable branch](https://github.com/antirez/redis/compare/4.0.6...unstable#diff-12ccdbf958c39a07b5dc785c68c8ebd3R1203) in the linked repo at the moment. The download page is currently listing 4.0.6 as the latest.

Comment: I am running 4.0.6 and the feature is there. Maybe the unstable branch is stale?

Comment: I suggest you to change `$cmd` to `eval $cmd`